# rubymine comment out rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

in rubymine it is easy to code out html with code -> line comment, but how do you comment multiple lines in ruby.

```
%= "this is a test %>
```

to

```
#= "this is a test %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the lines you want to comment out, and do `CMD+/` (forward slash) on a Mac. On a PC I'm assuming the same thing is `CTRL+/`

You can un-comment the same way, and you can also comment single lines out with the same keystroke. It doesn't really matter where your cursor is on the line. As long as a part of the line has been selected, the comment will include the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby does have multiline comments, although they use a relatively strange syntax:

```
=begin
some text or code here
=end
```

Note that both the `=begin` and `=end` delimiters have to be at the very beginning of the line, nothing else should be on the same line.

Comment: that is helpful -- i wish rubymine would automatically line comment out the region of interest. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

to comment some think like this

```
=begin
  your code is commented out
  this line is also commented
=end
```

select lines and press ctrl+shift+/
to comments some think like this

```
#your code is commented out
#this line is also commented
```

select lines and press ctrl+/